# What is the worst thing that can happen if I shutdown Windows while it installs system updates?

Tags: windows

Windows 7 sometimes tells us "Do not shutdown your computer" and wait for system updates to install.

I usually obey it and wait for it to complete. But what is the worst thing that can happen if I don't obey it and shutdown Windows 7 at the time? Would it compromise file system/OS integrity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The absolute worst thing that 'could' happen is total data loss......However, that's typically not the case and there are usually a lot 'fail safes' put in (so to speak) such that if a 'power failure' should happen (as would be the case in a forced shut down) you might have to do some basic system recover options (via F8 and 'safe mode') and possibly redo the updates, but usually nothing to worry about.

Of course I try and follow the 'rules' on this because there's always that chance it fails on a valuable boot file update :/

Sources: my own numerous forced power cycles during Windows updates

Answer (score 1):

The only thing that happens is you have to run them next time you turn the system on. Windows is clever enough to know shutdown can happen during updates for various reasons. The only reason it tells you not to shutdown is that the updates are important (....says Microsoft).

If shutting down during updates did anything, I would be so screwed by now.