# What is the worst thing that could happen to a computer when installing a software?

Tags: windows, windows-8, backup

Now I'm reading [this](http://www.whylinuxisbetter.net/switch/install/) about linux. And I find this really weird:

> You should first **backup all your data**. This is extremely important. We never know what may go wrong. No, really, I'm not kidding. Backup your data, get blank CDs, blank DVDs, another hard disk, whatever, but back up your work.

Is this guy over-exaggerating or is it true that something bad might happen to the computer? 
According to this: [question](https://superuser.com/questions/715737/what-is-the-worst-thing-that-can-happen-if-i-shutdown-windows-while-it-installs) a forced shutdown may cause data loss, but really I'm just installing something, what harm can that do?

Comment: On Windows, an installer is just a regular program; and on top of that, it's almost always run with Administrator privileges. Therefore it can do anything that a program could normally do, including installing adware/spyware, or deleting files, if its author was particularly malicious...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well for the first link you posted you are changing operating systems, it is very easy to do something during a OS install that will reformat the hard drive and there is no way to get your data back after that happens.

To answer the question in general, anything could happen when installing software, especially if the software you are installing is secretly malicious. When you install software you are usually performing that action as an administrator so anything can happen that the administrator can do, which is everything.

Now the question is the software you are installing going to do something bad? Well that is harder to answer, and is more of a personal judgment call on how well you know the software provider and did you get a copy of the software from a reputable source so you know it was not modified before it got to you.